# In the Monogatari series, why do we hear camera flash sounds?

Tags: monogatari-series

In the anime adaptation of *Monogatari* series, it's come to my attention that you often hear camera flash sounds when the character that narrates the arc blink. We first set a quick view of a specific spot (probably what the character is focused on) and then see the character's eyes blink with the sound of a camera flash.

The only theory I have so far is that things are going as they planned or they see an opportunity, but also it's possible that it happens because they're assimilating some information for later.

This question has really bugged me for a while and I haven't seen anyone else ask so I would love to hear from people.

Answer (score 1):

This can be just another Shaft Signature as their art style, without any reason, just a background effect, but still, we are talking about Monogatari, where everything can have a meaning, so my guess, when "camera flash" happens, the character considered that thing important enough to remember, you know, like IRL when you take a pic to something, you do it because you consider it interesting, worth to immortalise the moment, it may be the case in Monogatari, but again, can also be just a simple sound effect for more quality.